# Part of the update is not working in Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update

I have written two update statement in my procedure. For some strange reason first update statement only update some of the record (basically I update more than 100,000 rows). So second update statement works fine all the time. I brainstormed but procedure completes successfully but I am not getting what is the issue. Is there any way I can perform a validation check like how many got updated and and how many not?

**1st update statement(Which update only some records sometimes)**

```
UPDATE /*+PARALLEL(A,10,2)*/ VV_ACT_CALL_DET_DIS_EXTRACT A SET PRIORITY = 
       ( SELECT P.PRIORITY
         FROM   VV_ACT_CALL_DET_DIS P
         WHERE  P.CALL_ID = A.CALL_ID
         AND    P.PRODUCT_ID = A.PRODUCT_ID
         AND    P.IS_DELETED = A.IS_DELETED
         AND    ROWVAL = 1 )
WHERE  EXTRACT_STATUS = 'PENDING'
AND    EXISTS
       ( SELECT B.PRIORITY
         FROM   VV_ACT_CALL_DET_DIS B
         WHERE  B.CALL_ID=A.CALL_ID
         AND    B.PRODUCT_ID = A.PRODUCT_ID
         AND    B.IS_DELETED = A.IS_DELETED );
```

**2nd Update statement which updates record successfully all the time though condition is same as above**

```
UPDATE /*+PARALLEL(A,10,2)*/ VV_ACT_CALL_DET_DIS_EXTRACT A SET TYPE = 
       ( SELECT P.TYPE_VAL
         FROM   VV_ACT_CALL_DET_DIS P
         WHERE  P.CALL_ID = A.CALL_ID
         AND    P.PRODUCT_ID = A.PRODUCT_ID
         AND    P.IS_DELETED = A.IS_DELETED
         AND    ROWVAL = 1 )
WHERE  EXTRACT_STATUS = 'PENDING'
AND    EXISTS
       ( SELECT B.TYPE_VAL
         FROM   VV_ACT_CALL_DET_DIS B
         WHERE  B.CALL_ID = A.CALL_ID
         AND    B.PRODUCT_ID = A.PRODUCT_ID
         AND    B.IS_DELETED = A.IS_DELETED );
```

Comment: `update ... set (TYPE, PRIORITY)=(SELECT P.TYPE_VAL, P.PRIORITY ...)`

Comment: Its same Rene, just i am updating the priority field in first and in second i am updating the type field

Comment: @Mike Yes, will try to do that, but would help if you share any idea of validation check

Comment: Is not the same, because at first query you have ' EXISTS (select B.PRIORITY' and at second you have 'EXISTS (select B.TYPE_VAL'

Comment: @ShankarPanda Why there is an `ROWVAL = 1` in `SET`, but there is no in `EXISTS` ? I think this could be a problem

Comment: @Milaci `EXISTS` returns the presence of a row, the return value does not matter. `exists(select type_val)`, `exists(select priority)` and `exists(select 1)` are same

Comment: @ShankarPanda You are updating two fields with the same criteria, just do it in a single update statement.  Don't do twice what you can do once.  You'll generate double the redo.  "Is there any way i can perform a validation check like how many got updated and and how many not?"  You will not get any feedback what what you did NOT update, but SQL%ROWCOUNT will give you the number of records you DID updates if you are doing this within PL/SQL.

Answer (score 3):

You can query the updated row count using SQL%rowcount right after the update statement (before the commit), e.g.:

```
update ....
if sql%rowcount <> nnn then  --or = 0 or ...
  raise_application_error(-20001, 'invalid number of rows updated: ' || sql%rowcount);
end if;
```

Regarding the 'why it is not updating issue': without seeing that actual data it is hard to tell. Can you give us an example data set? Is it possible, that the first statement updates the same number of rows, but data does not change (priority remains the same)?

Comment: Surely the error message might as well say 'No whatevers were found for update' or something. What values of `sql%rowcount` are you expecting besides 0?

Comment: Maybe the OP would like to test if the two update statement affected the same number of rows, maybe only 0 is interesting. This was just an example, but I'm editing it for more clarity. .